# Is it possible to store a variable in an array or object and reference it to get the value of the variable and not the string name of the variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, audio

What I have is a series of sound files stored as variables.  I would like to create dynamic arrays so that certain sounds are populated depending upon certain criteria being met.

For example, I have below 3 sound files declared.

```
var E82 = new buzz.sound("https://github.com/CMGDesignStudios/Letters-and-Sounds/blob/master/LE0.mp3?raw=true");
var F87 = new buzz.sound("https://github.com/CMGDesignStudios/Letters-and-Sounds/blob/master/LE1.mp3?raw=true");
var FS92 = new buzz.sound("https://github.com/CMGDesignStudios/Letters-and-Sounds/blob/master/LE2.mp3?raw=true");
```

Under certain conditions, I may need the first two sound files.  Other times, I may need the 2nd two sound files.  So I created the following object.

```
var soundFileGroups = {criteria1:[E82,F87],
                       criteria2:[F87,FS92]};
```

I try to access what I need with

```
var currentSounds = soundFileGroups ["criteria1"];
```

or

```
var currentSounds = soundFileGroups ["criteria1"][0];
```

These both crash my program.

I have also tried to create the object as follows:

```
var soundFileGroups = {criteria1:"E82,F87",
                       criteria2:"F87,FS92"};
```

I can access this data with the following:

```
var currentSounds=soundFileGroups["criteria1"].split(',');
```

However, I only get a string with the name of the variable and do not know how to tell javascript to retrieve the data of the variable name that matches that string.

Is it possible in javascript to declare the value of several variables, place those variable names in an array or object and then access the value of the variable by indexing the variable name from the array or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To this question:

*However, I only get a string with the name of the variable and do not know how to tell javascript to retrieve the data of the variable name that matches that string.*

You can get the value of the variable using `eval`

```
var currentSounds=soundFileGroups["criteria1"].split(',');
//here currentSounds is an array of variable names.
//to get the value out of them do a for loop
currentSounds.forEach(function(sound){
  var val = eval(sound);
  console.log(val);
  //do your code with val
})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the name of the variable, you can access its value by `window[variableName]`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var soundFileGroups = {criteria1:"E82,F87",
                       criteria2:"F87,FS92"};
```

The above won't work because your are setting criteria1 and criteria2 to strings of characters that won't reference the variables you've created. When you split them into an array, they're still just strings of characters.

```
var soundFileGroups = {criteria1:[E82,F87],
                       criteria2:[F87,FS92]};`
```

You're on the right track here.  I think the key might be in how you're using the criteria.

```
var currentSounds = soundFileGroups ["criteria1"];
```

This line will give you an array containing `[E82, F87]`

```
var currentSounds = soundFileGroups ["criteria1"][0];
```

This will give you the first item in the criteria1 array `E82`

Let's say you want to play each sound in criteria1. You might try the following code.

```
var E82 = new buzz.sound("https://github.com/CMGDesignStudios/Letters-and-Sounds/blob/master/LE0.mp3?raw=true");
var F87 = new buzz.sound("https://github.com/CMGDesignStudios/Letters-and-Sounds/blob/master/LE1.mp3?raw=true");
var FS92 = new buzz.sound("https://github.com/CMGDesignStudios/Letters-and-Sounds/blob/master/LE2.mp3?raw=true");

var soundFileGroups = {
  criteria1:[E82, F87],
  criteria2:[F87, FS92]
};

var currentSounds = soundFileGroups.criteria1;

currentSounds.forEach(function(sound) {
  sound.play();
});
```